# How to override Magento backend theme

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, adminhtml, admin-order-create

I want to remove the Gift Wrapping from order total section on the create new order screen.

[image]

For the same I need to override this layout file:

```
vendor/magento/module-gift-wrapping/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_load_block_totals.xml
```

I tried overriding the file in this way:

```
app/design/adminhtml/Magento/backend/Magento_Giftwrapping/layout/sales_order_create_load_block_totals.xml
```

However it did not help me.

I can disable the module as well by running below command:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Giftwrapping
```

However the module is dependent on other module.

```
Unable to change status of modules because of the following constraints:
Cannot disable Magento_GiftWrapping because modules depend on it:
Magento_Enterprise: Magento_Enterprise->Magento_GiftWrapping
```

What is the best possible way I can remove Gift Wrapping from order total section?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a typo mistake.

Use

```
app/design/adminhtml/Magento/backend/Magento_GiftWrapping/layout/sales_order_create_load_block_totals.xml
```

instead of

```
app/design/adminhtml/Magento/backend/Magento_Giftwrapping/layout/sales_order_create_load_block_totals.xml
```

It's **Magento_GiftWrapping**(Captical 'W')